# Ktor (Netty) Configuration Values for Expected Load

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, netty, ktor

When configuring Ktor `embeddedServer` with Netty, there are three separate thread pools:

```
connectionGroupSize = XX  // accept new connections and start call processing
workerGroupSize = YY      // process connections, parse messages, do engine's internal work
callGroupSize = ZZ        // process application calls
```

There is [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-code.html#embedded-engine) about *what* they are (included in the comments above) but I couldn't find anything that explained what each of those phases actually means in the context of processing a request or how they relate to total capacity.

*If I have a server that is mostly accepting `GET` requests and returning content from a database with very little computational work (not even compression), how should these be configured to handle, say, 400 requests per second with up to 30 concurrent ones?*

(Assume that threads will not be able to operate as "coroutines", instead blocking for database lookups.)

Comment: You can find a better description of those parameters here (https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-file.html#predefined-properties). You can tweak those parameters to configure the server for optimal performance.

Comment: That page is the source for the "code" comments in my question.  It's really not much information, at least not to someone who doesn't have intimate knowledge of the `ktor` code.  What is "call processing"?  What are "application calls"?  How do they all relate?  When does one thread pass off work to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To really understand how connectionGroupSize, workerGroupSize, and callGroupSize work in Ktor with Netty and how to configure them for your specific scenario, you should look into the threading model of Netty.

I found this [Medium article](https://medium.com/@akhaku/netty-data-model-threading-and-gotchas-cab820e4815a) that discusses how threading works in Netty. The article references the book **Netty in Action**, which does a really good job explaining how EventLoops and Threading work (Chapter 7. EventLoop and threading model).

Now to answer your question as to what connectionGroupSize, workerGroupSize and callGroupSize actually do:

Netty uses a structure where each EventLoopGroup holds several EventLoops, with each EventLoop running on a separate thread to handle network tasks efficiently. This setup prevents task overlap and minimizes the need for switching between tasks, making the process more straightforward and error-free.

For server-side applications, Netty uses a ServerBootstrap object, which initializes with two EventLoopGroup instances: one for accepting connections (the connectionGroupSize in Ktor) and another for handling the actual connection's data processing (the workerGroupSize and callGroupSize in Ktor). The separation of these groups helps in balancing the load between accepting new connections and processing existing ones.

As for this part of your question:

*If I have a server that is mostly accepting GET requests and returning content from a database with very little computational work (not even compression), how should these be configured to handle, say, 400 requests per second with up to 30 concurrent ones?*

**connectionGroupSize**: Since the server mainly deals with accepting connections and the overhead for this is relatively low, you can keep this number small (2-4 would suffice).

**workerGroupSize**: This group for processing the connections and handling the network I/O. Given the high rate of requests, the workerGroupSize should be sufficiently large to handle the I/O operations smoothly. Starting with a value like 8-16 might be a good approach.

**callGroupSize**: This size should reflect the ability to handle concurrent application-level operations such as database queries. Since the operations are not computationally intensive but might be I/O bound due to database access, setting callGroupSize to a number like 30-50 can help manage the concurrent requests effectively, ensuring that database lookups do not become a bottleneck.

If you have any further questions related to the subject, I don't think you're going to find anything **detailed enough** in the Ktor documentation. You're going to need to dive deeper into how Netty works under the hood.

Goodluck!

Comment: That's great information, thanks!  Some clarifications...  Does "accepting connections" mean just the low-level socket `accept()` call or is something else involved as well?  "Handling the network I/O" means just HTTP traffic, inbound _and_ outbound?  For call processing, Objectify->GoogleDatastore doesn't support co-routines (last I checked) so the size should be the expected maximum number of concurrent DB requests?  Lastly, after loading the result from the DB and returning it, does that mark the end of the "call" thread and new work for the "worker" co-routine?

Comment: Looking through that _Medium_ post, it uses different names.  Am I reading it correctly that "EventLoop" is `connectionGroupSize`, "ChannelHandlers" is `workerGroupSize`, and "offloaded to a separate thread" is `callGroupSize`?

Comment: To answer your first question, "accepting connections" involves completing the TCP handshake, creating a new Channel object to represent the connection, setting up the ChannelPipeline with necessary handlers, and assigning the channel to an EventLoop. And you're right! "Handling the network I/O" means managing inbound and outbound HTTP traffic related to the requests and responses being processed by your server. You're also right about how the callGroupSize should reflect the expected maximum number of concurrent database requests that your server needs to handle.

Comment: Lastly, yes, loading results from the database and returning them does marks the end of the "call" coroutine.

Comment: connectionGroupSize defines how many threads Ktor will use inside the "boss" EventLoopGroup to handle incoming connections. while workerGroupSize defines the number of threads Ktor will use within the"worker" EventLoopGroup to handle network tasks like reading incoming requests, executing ChannelHandler logic, and sending responses. and finally, callGroupSize defines the size of the thread pool Ktor will use to execute coroutines that primarily handle blocking operations (like database queries).

Comment: To clarify further, ChannelHandlers define the processing logic, while Ktor's workerGroupSize determines the number of threads executing that logic.

Comment: Thanks for all that.  I've gone with `connectionGroupSize` of _cpus_ + 1, `workerGroupSize` of _cpus_ + 2, and `callGroupSize` of 300 (because I really have no idea how many outstanding DB requests there may be); I'll refine the last after observing it under real load.  One note: I think you meant "TLS Handshake" since TCP handshake would be done by the OS.  But since I'm using Google Cloud-Run, all the TLS stuff is handled externally.